# Rust: make macro accept enum name with variant as argument

Tags: rust, macros

I want to write a macro, that consumes an enum like this: `panic_wrapper!(PanicKind::Alloc, "can't allocate because of: {}", reason)`. I'm having problems with making the macro accept `PanicKind::Alloc`.

My current solution works, but I don't think, that it is really nice, because technically I'm deconstructing the Enum name from the variant.

```rust
macro_rules! panic_wrapper {
    ($enum:ident::$variant:ident, $($arg:tt)*) => {
        println!("error code={}", $crate::PanicKind::$variant.code());
        panic!($($arg)*)
    }
}

#[repr(u32)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum PanicKind {
    First,
    Second,
    Third,
}

impl PanicKind {
    fn code(&self) -> u32 {
        *self as u32
    }
}

fn main() {
    panic_wrapper!(PanicKind::Second, "hello {}", "there");
}
```

I'm wondering if I can write the macro definition simpler, i.e. don't deconstruct it with `$enum:ident::$variant:ident`. Also I have to hard code the module path of the enum into the macro with my current solution. Any ideas how I can improve this?

Comment: You want to use the [`path`](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/macros/minutiae/fragment-specifiers.html#path) specifier: `$kind:path`